# can't activate virtual enviroment

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am trying to activate a virtual environment making the environment worked fine, but when I try to activate it(source virt/Scripts/activate), it throws up

$ source activate
bash: $'\r': command not found
bash: activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r'' ash: activate: line 4:` deactivate () {

and I am a beginner and I am clueless about what I should do

Thanks!

Comment: Turn on logging with `set -x`, to see which command exactly produces the error mesage. Also, the error mesage suggests that one of your file may have a carriage return character in it (Hex 0d), so you could check for this too.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows

```
python -m venv virt
virt\scripts\activate
```

On Unix or MacOS

```
python -m venv virt
source virt/bin/activate
```